# Как по желанию любого из 2-х игроков выйти из цикла while () в игре "Угадай число" (js)

Tags: javascript

Игра на 2-х человек: **комп рандомно загадывает** число от 0 до 10.
Игроки по очереди пытаются угадать загаданное число.

В **моем варианте**:

1. выход из игры совершается только после 4-х нажатий  клавиши ' q ' или ESC или Отмена (пока не отработается цикл while);
2. если верный ответ дан с первого раза, то мой скрипт дает еще ввести числа оставшиеся 3 раза, чтоб игра окончательно завершилась (хотя идея такая: угадал число - игра закончилась).

```js
var vopros = parseInt(Math.random() * 10);
var igrok1 = '№1';
var igrok2 = '№2';
let otvet1, otvet2;

function game(otvet, gamer) {

  for (let i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
    var otvet = +prompt("Выход клавиша q. Угадай число от 0 до 10. Ход игрока : " + gamer);
    if (otvet = "q" || otvet == 'esc' || otvet == null) {
      break;
    }

    if (otvet == vopros) {
      alert("Число угадал игрок " + gamer);
      break;
    } else if (otvet > vopros) {
      alert("Чет-то много");
    } else if (otvet < vopros) {
      alert("Слишком мало");
    }
  } //for():end

} //function (): end


let n = 0
while (n < 4) {
  //искусственно ограничил кол-во попыток, чтоб не было бесконечного цикла

  game(otvet1, igrok1);
  n++

  game(otvet2, igrok2);
  n++

} //while ( ): end


alert("Было загадано:" + vopros);
```

Мои попытки:

1. применил цикл FOR  в надежде применить выход из игры  через break.
2. применил WHILE с лимитом (n<4), чтоб не уходить в бесконечный цикл.

**Сложность** в том, что не знаю как сделать, чтоб:

1. по желанию любого из игроков **выйти из игры в любой момент**: будь то  по нажатию клавиши ' q ' или ESC или Отмена.
2. в случае правильного ответа, игра должна **сразу прекратиться**.

Как можно **упростить код** для игры на 2 игрока; мои познания не позволяют перейти ту волшебную границу, чтоб раз - и код стал миниатюрным и быстрым.

Мой начальный вариант - до применения function () был такой:

```js
var vopros = parseInt(Math.random() * 10);
var igrok1;
var igrok2;

while (true) {
  var otvet1 = prompt("Выход клавиша q! Угадай число от 0 до 10. Ход игрока №1: ");
  if (otvet1 == "q") {
    break;
  }
  otvet1 = parseInt(otvet1); //иначе будет otvet1= Number, и не отработает выход q

  if (otvet1 == vopros) {
    alert("Число угадал игрок №1");
    break;
  } else if (otvet1 > vopros) {
    alert("Чет-то много");
  } else if (otvet1 < vopros) {
    alert("Слишком мало");
  }


  var otvet2 = prompt("Выход клавиша q! Угадай число от 0 до 100. Ход игрока №2: ");
  if (otvet2 == "q") {
    break;
  }
  otvet2 = parseInt(otvet2); //иначе будет otvet2 = Number, и не отработает выход через q 

  if (otvet2 == vopros) {
    alert("Число угадал игрок2");
    break;
  } else if (otvet2 > vopros) {
    alert("Чет-то много");
  } else if (otvet2 < vopros) {
    alert("Слишком мало");
  }

} //while ( ): end


alert("Было загадано:" + vopros);
```

Comment: У ответов на Ваши вопросы слева есть значок "галочка". Он там для Вас.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var vopros = parseInt(Math.random() * 10);
var igrok1 = '№1';
var igrok2 = '№2';
let otvet1, otvet2;

function game(otvet, gamer) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
    var otvet = prompt("Выход клавиша q. Угадай число от 0 до 10. Ход игрока : " + gamer);
    if (otvet == "q" || otvet == 'esc' || otvet == null) {
      return false;
    }
    otvet = +otvet;

    if (otvet == vopros) {
      alert("Число угадал игрок " + gamer);
      return false;
    } else if (otvet > vopros) {
      alert("Чет-то много");
    } else if (otvet < vopros) {
      alert("Слишком мало");
    }
  } //for():end

  return true;
} //function (): end


let n = 0;
while (n < 4) {
  //искусственно ограничил кол-во попыток, чтоб не было бесконечного цикла

  n++
  if (!game(otvet1, igrok1))
    break;

  n++
  if (!game(otvet2, igrok2))
    break;

} //while ( ): end

alert("Было загадано:" + vopros);
```

Comment: благодарю за помощь. Ваш код   как волшебство.

@Igor, thanks for the help. Your code is like magic.

Comment: @Trenersambo Пожалуйста. Успехов.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (n < 4) {
  //искусственно ограничил кол-во попыток, чтоб не было бесконечного цикла

  game(otvet1, igrok1);
  n++

  game(otvet2, igrok2);
  n++

}
```

Этот цикл вызывает обе функции по очереди, т.к. в функции `game()` еще и твой цикл `for()` в игре отсутствует поочередность у игроков, сначала идут все попытки у 1 игрока, а потом у 2 игрока.
По поводу выхода из игры при вводе в `prompt` буквы q, именно при вводе буквы, а не при нажатии на клавишу q, обработка событий клавиатуры это уже совсем другая история, и другая тема. А по поводу почему не выходит при вводе q, потому что указан `+prompt`  `+` приводит все что ты напишешь в prompt к числу, а приведенная к числу строка дает NaN.

Открой в браузере этот файл(без бесконечного цикла) открой отладчик, поставь кучу точек остановки, и смотри что чему равно, так и только так нужно начинать дебажить.
А вообще если что то не получается, то зачастую лучше вернутся к началу и переписать все заново.